# How do I edit a URL's location and use it for my code

Tags: python-3.x, rasa-core, rasa, rasa-x

I am trying to create a simple bot using rasa which runs on Python to extract data from an api.

To make explanations easier let us assume it is a corona tracker bot. So the api URL for the corona data is made so that the final section of it filters the api data to a specific set of data so for example:

https://exampleurl.com/api/corona/country/Germany

This means it only contains the data from Germany, but if i were to change it to Russia for example, then it would display the data from Russia.

What I want is that when someone tells my bot "*Please tell me how **Russia** is doing*" the bot will recognize first the correct intent and also that the entity is Russia. With that entity I want it to place it into the correct place of the URL and put that into a custom action which will extract the data from the api.

So to summarize I want that entity `<Country>` gets inputted into `https://exampleurl.com/api/corona/country/<country>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use python string concatenation to join 2 strings like so:

```py
country = "Russia"
url = "https://exampleurl.com/api/corona/country"
new_url = url + '/' + country
```

2. Use formatted string literals, introduced in [Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```py
new_url = f"{url}/{country}"
```